# Remove "www", "http://" from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I remove "www", "http://", "https://" from strings using Ruby?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
s.gsub('/(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)\/?$/i', '')
```

Here what I'm doing in Rails:

```
<%= auto_link(job.description) do |url| url.truncate(25).gsub('http://', '') end %>
```

Url are truncated, but my goal is to remove the beginning of the links, such as "www" or "http://" so the link would look like "google.com/somepage/d...", not like "http://google.com/some..."

Comment: [`String#sub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-sub-21)

Comment: I tried gsub with some regexes I found but nothing worked. For example this: s.gsub('/(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)\/?$/i', '')

Comment: What is the bigger problem you're trying to solve? Do you want to redirect "www.mydomain.com" to "mydomain.com"?

Comment: @MartinPetrov I've edited you question to include that, but please edit it further to include example input/output that didn't work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
s = s.sub(/^https?\:\/\//, '').sub(/^www./,'')
```

If you don't want to use `s =`, you should use `sub!`s instead of all `sub`s.

The problems with your code are:

1. Question mark always follows AFTER an optional character
2. Always replace one pattern in a sub. You can "chain up" multiple operations.
3. Use `sub` instead of `gsub` and `^` in the beginning of Regexp so it only replaces the `http://` in the beginning but leaves the ones in the middle.

Comment: Awesome answer. Here's an upgrade: `s.(/^https?\:\/\/(www.)?/,'')` ... and `.sub(/\/.*$/,'')` to remove the path

Comment: why `sub` instead of `gsub`?

Answer (score 5):

This method should catch all 3 variations:

```
def strip_url(url)
  url.sub!(/https\:\/\/www./, '') if url.include? "https://www."

  url.sub!(/http\:\/\/www./, '')  if url.include? "http://www."

  url.sub!(/www./, '')            if url.include? "www."

  return url
end

strip_url("http://www.google.com")
   => "google.com" 
strip_url("https://www.facebook.com")
   => "facebook.com" 
strip_url("www.stackoverflow.com")
  => "stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: @JuliusMarkūnas strip_url("stackoverflow.com") still returns the expected output.  What did you expect to be different?

Comment: @JuliusMarkūnas What does that return that is unexpected?

Comment: It does not remove http from beginning of url
`strip_url("http://stackoverflow.com") #=> "http://stackoverflow.com"

`

Answer (score 1):

```
def strip_url(target_url)
  target_url.gsub("http://", "")
            .gsub("https://", "")
            .gsub("www.", "")
end

strip_url("http://www.google.com")
 => "google.com" 
strip_url("https://www.google.com")
 => "google.com" 
strip_url("http://google.com")
 => "google.com"
strip_url("https://google.com")
 => "google.com" 
strip_url("www.google.com")
 => "google.com"
```