# Ruby - Editing URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, url, ruby-on-rails-4

I used the following question, [Remove "www", "http://" from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251094/remove-www-http-from-string), to remove the `HTTP` and `HTTPS` from my url.  Now I want to remove the path on the end of the url as well and can't seem to get the pattern.  This is the code I am trying to use:

```
str = str.sub(/^https?\:\/\//, '').sub(/^www./,'').sub(/^\/*/,'')
```

The first two `.sub` work as expected and remove the `HTTP`, `HTTPS` and `www.` from the url but the path i.e. `http://URL/path/to/remove/` stays with the URL.  As can be seen above I have tried the following pattern `/^\/*/` in the third sub but it doesn't remove the path on the end of the url.  What pattern will remove all characters after the base URL?

Comment: Do you want to get only the *host* part of the URL? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes exactly.  Sorry if that was unclear I hope my question is not too confusing.

Comment: It's worth noting that some sites, due to misconfigured DNS, do not have a working "non-dubs" alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could:

```
require 'uri'
URI('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252071/ruby-editing-urls').host
# => "stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: +1 It's almost always better to use a proper parsing library like this than to wreck around with regular expressions. Might want to amend to `host.sub(/^www\./, '')` as well.

Comment: URI isn't working when the user inputs a host name that is already in the proper form. i.e. google.com throws an exception when I try to to get the host with the URI method. What regular expression would get rid of any characters after the forward slash? @tadman

Comment: It needs to be a proper URL, not just a hostname. Are you trying something like `URI('google.com').host`?